# generate audio file with W3C Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

Is it possible to use W3C Web Speech API to write Javascript code which generates audio file (wav, ogg or mp3) with voice speaking given text? I mean, I want to do something like:

```
window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("0 1 2 3"))
```

but I want sound generated with it not to be output to speakers but to file.

Answer (score 5):

The requirement is not possible using Web Speech API alone, see [Re: MediaStream, ArrayBuffer, Blob audio result from speak() for recording?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jul/0005.html), [How to implement option to return Blob, ArrayBuffer, or AudioBuffer from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/352073/how-to-implement-option-to-return-blob-arraybuffer-or-audiobuffer-from-window)

Though requirement is possible using a library, for example, `espeak` or [`meSpeak`](http://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/), see [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346410/how-to-create-or-convert-text-to-audio-at-chromium-browser).

```js
fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/f48ee0658bc9b948766c67126ba9104c/raw/958dd72d317a6087df6b7297d4fee91173e0844d/mespeak.js")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return Promise.all([
      new Promise(resolve => {
        meSpeak.loadConfig("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/8421b50dfa0e5e7e5012da132567776a/raw/501fece4fd1fbb4e73f3f0dc133b64be86dae068/mespeak_config.json", resolve)
      }),
      new Promise(resolve => {
        meSpeak.loadVoice("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/fa0650d0e0159ac96b21beaf60766bcc/raw/82414d646a7a7ef11bb04ddffe4091f78ef121d3/en.json", resolve)
      })
    ])
  })
  .then(() => {
    // takes approximately 14 seconds to get here
    console.log(meSpeak.isConfigLoaded());
    console.log(meSpeak.speak("what it do my ninja", {
      amplitude: 100,
      pitch: 5,
      speed: 150,
      wordgap: 1,
      variant: "m7",
      rawdata: "mime"
    }));
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

There is also workaround using `MediaRecorder`, depending on system hardware [How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call/45003549#45003549).